# control copy files between two directories

Tags: bash

I need to copy files from one folder to another folder. In the first folder I have files...when I begin to copy from one folder to the other one, still I have not all the files...they are coming...so I need to copy the files testing if they are in the first folder...if they exist, copy to the other folder, if not, try sometimes till the file arrives. I have prepare the following code but it is not enough. I need help.

```
codi=( 000 003 006 009 012 015 018 021 024 027 030 033 036 039 042 045 048 051 054 057 060 )
for c in ${codi[@]};do

FILE=$dir1/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p50.f$c
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
echo "File $FILE exists"
cp  $dir1/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p50.f$c $dir2
else
echo "File $FILE does not exist"
cont=100
until [ $cont -lt 1 ];do
if [ -f "$FILE" ];then
cp  $dir1/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p50.f$c   $dir2
else
echo "still File $FILE does not exist" $FILE
fi
let cont-=1
echo "$cont"
sleep 3
done
sleep 10
fi
done
```

Now this code copies the files to the other folder, when one file isn't, the programme searches again the file after some seconds...but when the file arrives...the programme doesn't detect it...something in the loop may be bad...any help please...

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend, btw -- consider running code through it and addressing issue it finds before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

I love shell scripting, but this use case is better to be implemented through `rsync`

Refer [rsync manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for more information.

```
Local:  rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]
Access via remote shell:
  Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
  Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST
Access via rsync daemon:
  Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST::SRC... [DEST]
        rsync [OPTION...] rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/SRC... [DEST]
  Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST::DEST
        rsync [OPTION...] SRC... rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/DEST
```

There is an example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/317820/linux-continuously-synchronize-files-one-way)

You can also use inotifywait from the inotify-tools package.

```
inotifywait -r -m -e close_write --format '%w%f' /tmp | while read MODFILE
do
    echo need to rsync $MODFILE ...
done
```

Comment: You should consider showing an actual example instead of posting usage :-)

Comment: Upvote for rsync, but I agree that you should provide a simple example for the use case in question (local to local directory).